# How do we find the series expansion for $H_n^{(-1/2)}$

Tags: special-functions, laurent-series, harmonic-numbers

According to W.A., the series expansion at $n=\infty$ for the generalized harmonic series $H_n^{(-1/2)}$ is
$$H_n^{(-1/2)}=\frac{2n^{3/2}}3+\frac{\sqrt n}2+\zeta\left(-\frac{1}2\right)+\frac{1}{24\sqrt{n}}+O(1/n).$$

How would one go about proving this? The only thing I know about this function is that it is defined by $H_n^{(-1/2)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt k$.

Comment: Look up "Euler-Maclaurin formula" on the web. There are several decent expositions. Which one is the best for you depends on what you know already.

Comment: Almost duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900691/find-two-constantc-1-c-2-to-make-the-inequality-hold-true-for-all-n